# using the code for different set of ranges

Tags: vba, range, case

**Situation**
Hello SO,
I have a situation where, I have the following code which I would like to use over other ranges to. But in this case, when the case ranges changes, the clear contents and otehr defined ranges will also change. I find that I have to write a repeatative code for other ranges. Is it possible that I could possibly use another way to define my range and use this code for other range as well. To explain properly, I am finding it difficult but my aim is to optimize the program where I could do by not writing the code again and again but only change of ranges could be porrible.

```
Sub DescriptionisActivated()
Select Case Range("A12")
Case Is = ""
        If Sheet3.Range("B16") <> "" Then
        MsgBox "Input1" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "-Imput2", vbExclamation, " missing"
        Sheet3.Range("B16:L16").ClearContents: Sheet3.Range("A12").Select
        End If
Case Is <> ""
        If Sheet3.Range("B16") <> "" Then
         Sheet3.Range("P16").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0): Sheet3.Range("B16").Offset(0, 2).Select
        Else
        Sheet3.Range("N16").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0): Sheet3.Range("P16").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0): Sheet3.Range("N16,P16:S16").ClearContents: Sheet3.Range("B16").Select
        End If
End Select
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$B$16" Then
    Sheet3.Unprotect ""
    Call DescriptionisActivated
    Sheet3.Protect ""
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so if you change

```
Sub DescriptionisActivated()
```

to

```
Sub DescriptionisActivated(Target As Range)
```

and send it a range when you call it i.e.

```
Call DescriptionisActivated(Target)
```

then it has a range to start with.

Once that is done you need to change every range refence in DescriptionisActivated to rely on the Target Range.  So for example replace:

```
Range("P16")
```

with

```
Target.Offset(0, 14)
```

be careful as you do this to make ensure that they will point to the right cells that are required for each possible Target you would send to it

let me know how it goes!

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Can i possibly have the row Nr. 16 for example my activation cell is B16 and then corresponding columns with row 16 are my target. Can i write a code in such a way that, I use the same code for my activation cells B16 to B22 and corresponding target cells also corresponds to row n. 16 to 22. If not I have to write the same code for with diffrent row numbers for example 17 then 18 and so on.

Comment: And yes your suggestionw as helpful, but I am finding extremely difficult to put down my problem. Hope my last comments give a picture about the situation.

Comment: Hi, yeah try in a new sheet a new `Worksheet_Change` with just `Target.Offset(0, 14).Select` in it.  when you change b16 you'll see that p16 gets selected.  now you can adjust the `0,14` inside the offset to select any of the cells referenced in your code.  then start copy in the offset formula to replace the hardcoded values.  for example  `Target.Offset(0, 14)` can replace `Sheet3.Range("P16")` in your code.  then if b17 is sent the code will refer to p17 instead of p16 as the offset will start at b17 and move right 14 columns

Comment: yes, thank you. I guess, I am laerning it now. Need some time to implement but I get your suggestion. I will give feedback next day. Still working this out.

Comment: Thanks. It was quite helpful.

Comment: happy to help, do let me know if you have any other questions on it